# How do I submit the following kind of form, Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am new to FE development, so sorry if my question is naive.

I have a model in rails for `user` which can have multiple `profiles`. There are different types of `profiles` say `A`,`B` & `C`. Model `Profile` has a json field details, so `A`, `B` & `C` have different fields in details.

I am creating a form which has `user` fields, then a dropdown to choose between `A`,`B` or `C` for `profile` (nested attributes), which will render a partial form (I'm doing this using js). Some fields in each profile type are `required`, so If I'm submitting `B` type profile, I am unable to do it because of the required fields in `A` (`A` & `C` input fields are hidden). How do I submit this? (Submit button is in each partial form, and not outside, so both user and profile have to be saved simultaneously)

Also, is there a better way to render the partial form instead of rendering all forms and hiding them?

Additionally, how can I load the script in one partial form only instead of all of them (somewhat similar to above question)?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need a custom validation which takes the model type (A, B or C), and then checks for presence of only the fields required by that model. Checkout the Rails docs for [custom validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators), but the long and short of it is (inside your User model):

```
put validates :check_presence

def check_presence
  if this.model == "a"
    errors[:fieldX] = "cannot be empty" if this.fieldX.empty? 
  elsif this.model == "b"
    etc...
  end
end
```

The way custom validations work is that if you put anything in `errors`, the validation fails. It's up to you in your controller to then render that error using something like `render json: @user.errors`